# Webservice to add users to SharePoint (like SPWeb.EnsureUser)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to add a user to a SharePoint-Website (WSS 3.0) via a Web Service.

Using the API I would use the [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) method, but I can't run my own code on the server.
I was hoping the [Users and Groups Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772647.aspx) could help, but it does not provide a suitable method.

So, is there a Web Service equivalent to SPWeb.EnsureUser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I stumbled across this question yesterday. As a matter of fact, there is a Web Service equivalent of `web.EnsureUser`, but it is not in the **UserGroup** Web service. Use the `ResolvePrincipals` method of the **People** web service (*_vti_bin/people.asmx*) instead.

[Here is the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/people.people.resolveprincipals%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The key is to feed in `true` for the value of `addToUserInfoList`. The `PrincipalInfo` object returned by the service call includes a `UserInfoID`, which you can use in other membership-related operations on that site.

Here is an example of using the web service from **PowerShell 2.0**:

```
$client = new-webserviceproxy http://mysharepointsite/_vti_bin/people.asmx?wsdl -usedefault
$person = $client.ResolvePrincipals(@('domain\user'), 'User', $true)
# ...
```

Comment: You can also use [`SearchPrincipals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/people.people.searchprincipals%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to identify whether the principal has been added to the site collection yet. Checking the [`PrincipalInfo.UserInfoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/people.principalinfo%28v=office.12%29.aspx) will return a value > -1 if the principal has been added to the site collection users already.